# statistically analyse pass rate of test in different locations

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I'm looking to analyse some data and as it's been a long time since my statistics days I'd like to know which area of statistics my problem lies.

Lets say I have a number of different driving schools, each doing the same test of their student drivers' ability to have a licence.

Now every month or so I might want to analyse if a particular driving school is "letting people through" easily meaning a *significant* percentage of people are passing, or conversely, is being too strict and a *significant* percentage of people are failing.

Now I've done some reading and lots of things came flooding back... and I think we're talking about standard deviation and statistical significance. Although what I've read about the latter tends to imply that we need two sets of data to imply some causal relationship, whereas I'm looking at each school against the mean of their pass rate for the month ...or potentially each school against itself over time or something...?

Can someone give me some pointers as to where to start?

**Edit:** I just discovered stats.stackexchange.com so I'll put it there instead.  Please let me know how to remove it from here...